# CUDA: Is this the correct way to copy image array from the device memory?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, steganography

I'm trying to do a project on Steganography. For which I'm using CUDA to parallelize the task. But I'm getting an incomplete result. The final image(**recovered.png**) which is supposed to be extracted from the stego image(**stego.png**) incorrect. Only the first few rows of the final image are correctly portrayed.
I've written three kernel functions as shown below.

```
__global__ void printRec(unsigned char* rec){
        int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int bz = blockIdx.z;
    int bsizeX = blockDim.x;  //WIDTH of the message image
    int bsizeZ = blockDim.z;  // CHANNELS in the message image
    int tx = threadIdx.x;

    int recoveredIdx = by * (bsizeX * bsizeZ) + bx * bsizeZ + bz;
    printf("%d\t",rec[recoveredIdx]);
}


/* Embedding image by setting off the last bit of the pixel value of the cover image
& ORing with the extracted bit of the message image pixel */
__global__ void encodeMessageImage(unsigned char *coverImg, unsigned char *messageImg)
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int bz = blockIdx.z;
    int bsizeX = blockDim.x;  //WIDTH of the message image
    int bsizeZ = blockDim.z;  // CHANNELS in the message image
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    // PIXEL_SIZE =
    int messageIdx = by * (bsizeX * bsizeZ) + bx * bsizeZ + bz;
    int coverIdx = by * (bsizeX * bsizeZ  * PIXEL_SIZE) + bx * bsizeZ * PIXEL_SIZE + bz * PIXEL_SIZE + tx;

    char coverPixel = coverImg[coverIdx];
    char pixel = messageImg[messageIdx];

    coverPixel &= LSB_OFF_MASK;  // LSB_OFF_MASK = 0xFE
    char extractedBit = pixel & MASK[tx];

    extractedBit = extractedBit >> (PIXEL_SIZE - tx - 1);
    if (extractedBit & 0x80000000 || (int)extractedBit < 0)
        extractedBit = 0x01;
    coverPixel |= extractedBit;

    coverImg[coverIdx] = coverPixel;
}

/* extracting image from stego image by extracting the last bit from the stego image 
 pixel value and reconstructing the pixel of the recovered image(hidden image) */
__global__ void decodeMessageImage(unsigned char *stegoImg, unsigned char *recoveredImg)
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int bz = blockIdx.z;
    int bsizeX = blockDim.x;  //WIDTH of the message image
    int bsizeZ = blockDim.z;  // CHANNELS in the message image
    int tx = threadIdx.x;

    int recoveredIdx = by * (bsizeX * bsizeZ) + bx * bsizeZ + bz;
    int stegoIdx = by * (bsizeX * bsizeZ  * PIXEL_SIZE) + bx * bsizeZ * PIXEL_SIZE + bz * PIXEL_SIZE + tx;

   __shared__ char recoveredBlock[PIXEL_SIZE];
    char recoveredPixel = 0x00;
    char stegoPixel = stegoImg[stegoIdx];

    char extractedBit = stegoPixel & LSB_ON_MASK; // LSB_ON_MASK = 0x01
    extractedBit = extractedBit << (PIXEL_SIZE - tx - 1);

    recoveredBlock[tx]=extractedBit;
    __syncthreads();
     if(tx==0){
        for(int i=0;i<PIXEL_SIZE;i++){
            recoveredPixel |= recoveredBlock[i];
        }
    recoveredImg[recoveredIdx] = recoveredPixel & 0xff;
     }
}
```

I'm  using *stb_image_write.h* & *stb_image.h* library, whose functions `stbi_load()` & `stbi_write_png()` I've modified as `read_image()` & `write_image_array()` respectively, which are working fine as I've created **stego.png** with them, which was correctly generated.
Also, I've used a kernel function `printRec()`  to store pixel values stored in the image array (`d_recoveredImg`) in the device memory to a file(**main_log.txt**). I'm getting varying pixel counts(around 20K) way less than the actual pixel counts of the original hidden image(**message.png**).
Below is the **main.cu** calling the kernel functions and doing all the allocations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stego.h"
#include "imageio.h"
void cudaErrorCheck(){
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    printf("\n%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));
}
enum RGB {RED,GREEN,BLUE};
int main()
{
    const unsigned char HOST_MASK[PIXEL_SIZE] = {0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01};
    char COVER_IMG_PATH[] = "cover.png";
    char MESSAGE_IMG_PATH[] = "message.png";
    char STEGO_IMG_PATH[] = "stego.png";
    char RECOVERED_IMG_PATH[] = "recovered.png";

    unsigned char *coverImg, *messageImg, *stegoImg, *recoveredImg, *d_coverImg, *d_messageImg, *d_stegoImg, *d_recoveredImg;
    int coverWidth, coverHeight, coverChannels, messageWidth, messageHeight, messageChannels;

    coverImg = read_image(COVER_IMG_PATH, &coverWidth, &coverHeight, &coverChannels);
    messageImg = read_image(MESSAGE_IMG_PATH, &messageWidth, &messageHeight, &messageChannels);

    messageChannels =coverChannels =DESIRED_CHANNELS; // DESIRED_CHANNELS = 3
    int coverSize = sizeof(unsigned char) * coverChannels * coverHeight * coverWidth;
    int messageSize = sizeof(unsigned char) * messageChannels * messageHeight * messageWidth;

    recoveredImg = (unsigned char *)malloc(messageSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_coverImg, coverSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_messageImg, messageSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_stegoImg, coverSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_recoveredImg, messageSize);

    cudaMemcpy(d_coverImg, coverImg, coverSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_messageImg, messageImg, messageSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(MASK, HOST_MASK, sizeof(HOST_MASK), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    /* GRID is same as message.png dimensions &  
       each block is responsible for encoding and decoding each bit of the pixel value 
       into and from respective pixels in the cover.png */  

    dim3 grid = {messageWidth, messageHeight, messageChannels};
    dim3 block = {PIXEL_SIZE, 1, 1};

    /*------Encoding starts here---------*/

    encodeMessageImage<<<grid, block>>>(d_coverImg, d_messageImg);

    cudaErrorCheck();

    cudaMemcpy(coverImg, d_coverImg, coverSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Writing back modified cover to STEGO_IMG_PATH
    write_image_array(STEGO_IMG_PATH, coverImg, coverWidth, coverHeight, coverChannels); 
    
   

    /*------Decoding starts here-------*/

    stegoImg = read_image(STEGO_IMG_PATH, &coverWidth, &coverHeight, &coverChannels);
    coverChannels=DESIRED_CHANNELS; 

    cudaMemcpy(d_stegoImg, stegoImg, coverSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    decodeMessageImage<<<grid, block>>>(d_stegoImg, d_recoveredImg);

    cudaMemcpy(recoveredImg, d_recoveredImg, messageSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //printRec<<<grid,block>>>(d_recoveredImg);

    write_image_array(RECOVERED_IMG_PATH, recoveredImg, messageWidth, messageHeight, messageChannels);
    free(stegoImg);
    free(recoveredImg);
    free(coverImg);
    free(messageImg);

    cudaFree(d_coverImg);
    cudaFree(d_messageImg);
    cudaFree(d_stegoImg);
    cudaFree(d_recoveredImg);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Link to all the relevant files & images mentioned above: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13F1z7klcGrZlJnTOsGPwMSvIDmm9LtPR?usp=sharing

Comment: Should it be (int)extractedBit > 0 ?

Comment: I get 1 copied every time I shift right in the case where the extractedBit = 0x80, which I was getting as a negative Integer when converted to int. Hence, checking for negative ints to convert it to 0x01.

Comment: Okay, understand (so unrelated to result). Probably because extractedBit is of type char - and not unsigned char - shifting right in the line before the if will keep the sign.

Comment: Yup,you're right. Luckily,I found my mistake. just solved it. Actually in both kernels, it should be bsizeX =gridDim.x and bsizeZ= gridDim.z ( not bsizeX = blockDim.x & bsizeZ = blockDim.z) . blockDim.x = PIXEL_SIZE but I want message image's width, hence generating partial result.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the partial result issue. Actually, the variables `bsizeX` & `bsizeZ` are not equal to the intended message Width and no of color channels respectively, they are equal to `PIXEL_SIZE` and `1`, hence the partial result. So the modifications in the kernel `encodeMessageImage` & `decodeMessageImage` are:

```
    int bsizeX = gridDim.x;  //WIDTH
    int bsizeZ = gridDim.z;  // CHANNELS
```

Anyway, I will be happy to receive any suggestions you want to give or have. Thanks.

Comment: Some small suggestions: The Mask could be easily created on the fly by a shift operation. Simple math is typically more performant than memory accesses. Your blocks are way too small. Should be multiples of a warp (32) and typically 128-1024 threads. Otherwise you would waste speed. I would put a device sync into the error check function for debugging purposes (and probably remove it for fast asynchronous calls in production releases). The device reset at the end serves no real purpose.

Comment: The combining of the 8 bits can be more efficiently be done by shuffle instructions https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-examples-reduction

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian, these suggestions are really helpful. Will surely implement those.

Comment: Cuda programming is a balance between easy-to-read algorithm and optimizations. Those are suggestions - so feel free to try them out. Also use the Nsight Compute Profiler - it helps to understand, how Cuda works: The kernel launch statistics, the kernel running time, the warp states and stalls, the instructions and instruction pipelines, the memory accesses and caches, the number of times each code line is executed, the SASS representation of each line. Just start it, point to your executable, launch, activate Auto Profile and Run.

Comment: Ok, just saw that the device reset ist now recommended: "cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces."